# Unable to Step into Async Task

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

I've tried to get this to work via the multitude of similar "How to debug async tasks" posts and articles, but am still unable to step into or get a breakpoint to trigger in my WPF app's Async methods. regardless of how I start or run my task, or whether CLR exceptions are selected or not.

As for why a task, I really only want my WPF app's UI to remain responsive while the work is being done so that the UI can be used to queued other work while the app is thinking.

**Update 1:** It appears that the breakpoints aren't being hit if a line of code that comes **after?!?!** the breakpoint throws an exception.
The exception it's self is just a File.IO exception (that I'll fix shortly) of which there were a quite a few file operations to sort through, one included as the requested minimum example. (The exception doesn't contain a stack trace to determine which specific line is throws it without manually commenting them out, one at a time.)

Specifically,

```
const string APP_REG_NAMESPACE = "[Redacted]";

IProgress<int> progress;
IProgress<string> status;

public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    //Allows UI to remain responsive while work is being done.
    progress = new Progress<int>(UpdateProgress);
    status = new Progress<string>(UpdateStatus);
    
    //exceptions only appear here.
    Task.Run(() => EvalConfig(progress, status));
}

/*Removed as seemed un-needed
async Task Async_EvalConfig() {
    progress = new Progress<int>(UpdateProgress);
    status = new Progress<string>(UpdateStatus);

    //exceptions all thrown here.
    await Task.Run(() => EvalConfig(progress, status));
}*/

//This allows breakpoints to be hit on any of the 3 lines
void EvalConfig(IProgress<int> progress, IProgress<string> status) {
    //Give system a second (or 10)
    Task.Delay(5000);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return;
}

//No breakpoints are ever hit, if an exception occurs anywhere, 
//even if on only the last line. 
//Exceptions are only shown at the line that actually runs the task.
void EvalConfig(IProgress<int> progress, IProgress<string> status) {
    //Give system a second
    await Task.Delay(500);
    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    //Some long duration IO work done here to prepare data load.
    //[Redacted for brevity]

    //Check the registry for the protocol key
    if(TryGetProtocol(out string protocol)){
        //Use the protocol to connect and start doing some painfully slow work
        //[Truncated for brevity]
    }else{
        //Handle missing protocol logging and schedule for admin repair.
        //[Truncated for brevity]
    }
}

bool TryGetProtocol(out string strProtocol) {
    strProtocol = "";
    try {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(APP_REG_NAMESPACE)) {
            if (key == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Object o = key.GetValue("");//AKA (Default)
                if (o == null) {
                    return false;
                }

                strProtocol = (o as String);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strProtocol)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    //Oddly this didn't actually catch the error 
    //despite being super generic.
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Handle notification of exception.
        //[Truncated for brevity]
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: have you tried putting in a break point at the top of your EvalConfig method? Are you sure that the EvalConfig method is even getting executed?

Comment: remove the `Task.Run` wrapper around your async method.  Do `await EvalConfig(progress, status);`

Comment: Where does `mycolelction` come from? Does it contain anything? BTW you don't need two `IProgress` instances, you can use just one with a more complex payload, eg an `(int,string)` tuple or a class with two or more fields.

Comment: `Async_EvalConfig().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is simply wrong though. It *blocks execution* so the form will never be displayed. If `mycolelction` is a field or propety, it will never get any value because the window's constructor won't finish until `Async_EvalConfig` does. Assign the `Task` returned by `Async_EvalConfig()` to a field and await it only if you really need to wait for it to finish.

Comment: @TJ Rockefeller, tried that, it's getting called and somewhere inside the exception occurs, but no breakpoints inside ever get hit.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, the actual code is something like 150 lines of business logic evaluating multiple collections, objects, etc.., I just truncated it to a basic foreach loop for debugging the debugger. I used to not use the awaiter and just had the Task.Run in the constructor, but the debugger still wouldn't hit a break point anywhere inside EvalConfig.

Comment: @Jonesopolis just using 'await EvalConfig(progress, status);' has the same result/effect as the Task.Run. There's got to be something im missing as to why breakpoints inside an async, or a task aren't triggering.

Comment: Should I just change the simple Tasks for a fully realized `BackgroundWorker`? it just seems like overkill to go that in-depth.

Comment: @Reahreic: Please post a minimal repro, and then we can see what's wrong.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary will posted edited code example shortly as I've been able to get the break point to fire if I only have a Task.Delay or Thread.Sleep and a return in a non async method. Ironically I was just reading one of your blog posts about tasks.

Comment: @Reahreic the bug in the code you posted is in the constructor, not the loop. If that's not the real code, post something that reproduces the actual problem. You don't need to do anything special to get tasks and Progress to work. You don't need the obsolete BackgroundWorker. A BGW is harder to use, offering no way to combine tasks.

Comment: @Reahreic the code you posted forces `Async_EvalConfig` to run and *complete* inside the constructor. This means all fields will have their default values and the window itself won't be displayed until `Async_EvalConfig` finishes. Any progress updates will be lost, simply because there's no visible window to display them

Comment: @Reahreic if you wanted `Async_EvalConfig` to run in the background, you should call it *after* you populate any collections it needs and **await** it, not block. If you initialize the collections in the constructor, you should store the task in a field `_evalTask= Async_EvalConfig();` and await the task to complete somewhere else. Another option is to start and await the task in the `Initialized` or `Loaded` event handlers

Comment: Have you considered moving this out the ctor and into the loaded event instead? You could make that async and just await a task. Then you'd definitely have a mainwindow. As it is you're risking errors in the thing constructs your mainwindow. No mainwindow = bad.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I've updated the post with more detail, but can't really post the actual code as it's around 700-1200 lines and much of it doesn't pertain to why break points don't trigger if there's an exception. I'll do more reading on async tasks to get the blocking/non-blocking behaviour correct, I assumed that by not awaiting that the specifically, that it Task didn't block the constructor's completion.

Comment: @Reahreic `await` is used to *avoid* blocking. If you use `.Result`, `.Wait()` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` you are *explicitly* blocking

Comment: @Andy Good mention on the Loaded event, I don't create UWP apps often (1-2  a year if that) and completely forgot about it and just used the default template.

Comment: Reahreic could you add some line-breaks in the code, so that it's all visible without horizontal scrolling? Vertical scrolling is fine, horizontal scrolling is awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but the closest I came to getting breakpoints to hit again.

It appears that the breakpoints won't be hit on Tasks/Async Code if an exception is thrown anywhere in the task's thread. This strange behavior debugger was caused by an unhandled exception even though that exception occurred **after?!?!** the breakpoint.

To future searchers, you may not be able to step into/through your Task code with the VS debugger until you clear all unhandled exceptions. (even if the program compiles happily)